# How to get product type in magento minicart?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2minicart

I want to get product type in magento 2 minicart so as to apply some conditions over the look and feel of item in minicart.

The file is located here : `/var/www/html/project/app/design/frontend/Solwin/freego_child/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/item/default.html`

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<li class="item product product-item" data-role="product-item">
    <div class="product">
        <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url, title: product_name}" tabindex="-1" class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </a>
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
        <span class="product-item-photo">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('itemImage') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_image} --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </span>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <div class="product-item-details">
            <strong class="product-item-name">
                <!-- ko if: product_has_url -->
                <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: product_name"></a>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: product_has_url -->
                    <!-- ko text: product_name --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </strong>

            <!-- ko if: options.length -->
            <div class="product options" data-mage-init='{"collapsible":{"openedState": "active", "saveState": false}}'>
                <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'See Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>

                <div data-role="content" class="content">
                    <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
                    <dl class="product options list">
                        <!-- ko foreach: { data: options, as: 'option' } -->
                        <dt class="label"><!-- ko text: option.label --><!-- /ko --></dt>
                        <dd class="values">
                            <!-- ko if: Array.isArray(option.value) -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value.join('<br>')"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && option.option_type == 'file') -->
                                <span data-bind="html: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                            <!-- ko if: (!Array.isArray(option.value) && option.option_type != 'file') -->
                                <span data-bind="text: option.value"></span>
                            <!-- /ko -->
                        </dd>
                        <!-- /ko -->
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->

            <div class="product-item-pricing">
                <!-- ko if: canApplyMsrp -->
                
                <div class="details-map">
                    <span class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Price'"></span>
                    <span class="value" data-bind="i18n: 'See price before order confirmation.'"></span>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko ifnot: canApplyMsrp -->
                <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('priceSidebar') -->
                <!-- ko template: {name: getTemplate(), data: item.product_price, as: 'price'} --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                
                <div class="details-qty qty">
                    <label class="label" data-bind="i18n: 'Qty', attr: {
                    for: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty'}"></label>
                    <div class="more">+</div>
                        <input data-bind="attr: {
                        id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                        'data-cart-item': item_id,
                        'data-item-qty': qty,
                        'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                        }, value: qty"
                        type="number"
                        size="4"
                        class="item-qty cart-item-qty">
                    
                    <div class="less">-</div>
                    <button data-bind="attr: {
                    id: 'update-cart-item-'+item_id,
                    'data-cart-item': item_id,
                    title: $t('Update')
                    }"
                    class="update-cart-item"
                    style="display: none">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Update'"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="product actions">
                <!-- ko if: is_visible_in_site_visibility -->
                <div class="primary">
                    <a data-bind="attr: {href: configure_url, title: $t('Edit item')}" class="action edit">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Edit'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- /ko -->
                <div class="secondary">
                    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-cart-item': item_id, title: $t('Remove item')}"
                       class="action delete">
                        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Remove'"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="message notice" if="$data.message">
        <div data-bind="text: $data.message"></div>
    </div>
</li>
```

And the code for `minicart.phtml` is

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer */
?>

<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <a class="action showcart" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getShoppingCartUrl()) ?>"
       data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <span class="text"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('My Cart')) ?></span>
        <span class="counter qty empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false && !isLoading() },
               blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
            <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()):?>
        <div class="block block-minicart"
             data-role="dropdownDialog"
             data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
            <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons') ?>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php $scriptString = <<<script
            require(['jquery'], function ($) {
                $('a.action.showcart').click(function() {
                    $(document.body).trigger('processStart');
                });
            });
script;
        ?>
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderTag('script', [], $scriptString, false); ?>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderTag('script', [], 'window.checkout = ' .
     /* @noEscape */ $block->getSerializedConfig(), false); ?>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-block='minicart']": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?= $block->escapeJs(
                $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'))
            ) ?>"
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
     require(['jquery'], function($){ 
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("[data-block='minicart']").on("dropdowndialogopen", (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(".block-minicart").hide();
                //$(".block-minicart").slideDown("slow");       
                $(".block-minicart").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);          
            });
            $("[data-block='minicart']").on("dropdowndialogclose", (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(".mage-dropdown-dialog").show();
                //$('.block-minicart').slideUp("slow");
                $('.block-minicart').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500);
            });


            $('body').on("click",".more, .less",function(){
                var obj = $(this);
                var currentQty = obj.siblings('.cart-item-qty').val();
                var iid = obj.siblings('.update-cart-item').attr('data-cart-item');

                if(obj.hasClass('more')){
                    var newAdd = parseInt(currentQty)+parseInt(1);
                    obj.siblings('.cart-item-qty').val(newAdd);
                    obj.siblings('.cart-item-qty').attr('data-item-qty',newAdd);
                    //$('#update-cart-item-'+iid).click();
                    //$('.update-cart-item').show();
                    $('.update-cart-item').trigger('click');
                } else {
                    if(parseInt(currentQty) > 1){
                        var newAdd = parseInt(currentQty)-parseInt(1);
                        obj.siblings('.cart-item-qty').val(newAdd); 
                        obj.siblings('.cart-item-qty').attr('data-item-qty',newAdd);
                        //$('#update-cart-item-'+iid).click();
                        //$('.update-cart-item').show();
                        $('.update-cart-item').trigger('click');
                    }
                }
            });

        });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At `default.html`, you can get product type by `product_type`.

```
<!-- ko text: product_type --><!-- /ko -->
```